# Detail Grid in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

I want a detail grid kind of control in MFC, where on expanding each row of the grid an embedded dialog would appear for it (not a popup but inside the same parent control, inside which I can show other controls).

Can you please point me if there is any such existing library providing this kind of a control? Or else how to go about implementing it. I want to do it in C/C++, MFC, Win32.

Best,
Sourabh

Comment: I don't know if codeproject's Ultimate Grid can support what you want, but it deserves a look.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Codejock Xtreme Toolkit Pro ([Link](http://www.codejock.com/products/toolkitpro/)). I had the opportunity to use its Grid Control to create an excel like sheet in MFC. It was quite good for my needs.

Refer to [this link](http://www.codejock.com/products/propertygrid/tour_15.asp?platform=mfc), i think it has what you are looking for.

HTH